# Add block with taxonomy terms in intergrated View Taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks

I'm using one content type that has taxonomy terms. With default view "taxonomy term" that comes with Views 3, I've managed to display the content with taxonomy terms in different menu pages based on taxonomy terms.

Now I want to add a block that will use the same terms, with one more field that will be different and will appear over the taxonomy term content.

EDIT

When I add the block into the default taxonomy term view and activating it into structure -> blocks in content region, it's not rendering in the pages.

Do I have to change something in the views block?

I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: Please define "didn't work" - can't add a block? Can add it but it's not shown in structure -> blocks? It is shown there, but is not rendered?..

Comment: I've added the block in structure -> blocks in a "content" region, but when I check the taxonomy pages, the block is not rendered.

Comment: Please use [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/88939/edit) to provide such explanations :) Comments are second-class citizens and may get deleted easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching and tweaking the views, finally I've found the solution and I'll post it here, so might be useful for someone.

Since a blocks are little "dumb" and it doesn't possess a path it is necessary to do a bit more configuration to achieve the result. So, here the solution:

Click on the contextual filter on the block view form in views.
Under "When the filter value is NOT available" select "Provide default value"

IF the page in the path is a taxonomy term Choose "Taxonomy term ID from URL" from the Type drop-down box and check "Load default filter from term page". That's all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem in argument. If you want display content by term id, you should use term id as argument in your views display. You can use "contextual filters" and "Argument input" from context.

Comment: The block is using the same settings for "contextual filters" like the default taxonomy term view.